# At onResume() how to identify if onPause() was called because of screen lock or app minimised

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding, android-developer-api

I have a binder service which binds at onResume. At onResume I want to check if the previous onPause was called because of app minimised or screen was lock by lock button.
I have tried with ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and setting a boolean value, but the problem is my binder at onResume get called before receiver gets the value.

Comment: Add your code what you tried

Answer (score 0):

use below `code` to detect whether `screen` is locked in `onPause()` method

```
KeyguardManager km= (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if( km.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
 //Screen is locked
} else {
 //it is not 
}
```